# Experiences with Redux and Redux-Observable middleware for handling Asynchronous Http Requests

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-observable

I am learning and trying redux in a typescript react environment. So far I have managed to get basic small web application implemented and am at the stage where I would like to refactor and improve the architecture.

I am using "typescript-actions" and custom factory methods to facilitate creating actions for Api request, success and failure payload types. I am using a wrapper around http library and have decided upon Axios due to its availability in both node and browser environments. This means no poly fills required when testing with tools such as jest.

I have decided upon "redux-observable" to handle API middleware.
I am currently trying to create a generic factory method that creates an epic(middleware handler) that handles an API Request. I am thinking along the lines of one generic factory method per request flow, e.g. providing a factory method to create an epic handler for:

1. DELETE, SUCCESS, FAIL FLOW
2. GET, SUCCESS, FAIL FLOW
3. POST, SUCCESS, FAIL FLOW
4. PUT, SUCCESS, FAIL FLOW

Currently, struggling to get this transpiling with Typescript as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58823453/how-to-create-generic-async-request-epics-that-uses-typesafe-actions-asynccreato).

What are others doing in their production environments with respect to handling asynchronous API requests? For example:

1. Not using redux at all to process intermediary API request states. Instead react components make and handle the request. The response is handled directly or dispatched onto the store once completed.
2. Using a dedicated epic for each individual resource type API flow:

   - Epic1=FETCH_RESOURCE1, SUCCESS_RESOURCE1, FAIL_RESOURCE1
   - Epic2=FETCH_RESOURCE2, FETCH_SUCCESS_RESOURCE2, FETCH_FAIL_RESOURCE2
   - EpicN=PATCH_RESOURCEN, PATCH_SUCCESS_RESOURCEN, PATCH_FAIL_RESOURCEN

3.Using a generic factory method to create each individual middleware flow. Each factory method accepting reusable parameters and generics such as url, parameters, body data type etc.

Each epic handler for option 2 would likely include duplicate code with the exception that each implementation would include different data such as request url, method, parameters, request body data type etc.

Many of the resources and examples that I have read so far hard code each individual API resource request flow. For example, hardcoding flows for Product, hardcoding flows for Customer etc. Subsequently, duplicate code is the result. How are others tackling this problem in their production environments?